# Can't start server using pserve

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, server, pyramid

I have one problem. I created a project in Pyramid Python framework. Everything is okay but when I want to start server using command `pserve development.ini`, I get message:

```
(env) miskos-air:ApiServer Mihael$ pserve development.ini
```

> invalid command name 'development.ini'

```
(env) miskos-`air:ApiServer` Mihael$
```

Comment: Is `development.ini` in your current working directory? Also I notice you have activated your virtual environment named `env`, which is not a problem if you are familiar with its effects, but for those unfamiliar it often causes confusion.

Comment: @StevePiercy, yes development.ini is in my current working directory. Actually I got this problem when I tryng change data from development.ini, first time when I started server I got error "ImportError: No module named MySQLdb", so I added +pymysql to my sqlalcemy route "sqlalchemy.url = mysql+pymysql://iss:iss@127.0.0.1:3306/iss?use_unicode=1&chars$".. and I got that message invalid command name

Comment: You need to be clear about what is the problem by editing your question, not adding more comments. Be clear about (1) what you did, (2) what you expected, and (3) what you observed including any complete error messages or stack trace. Also include how to reproduce the issue using a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).